# How to proper add NameValueCollection to Properties.Settings

Tags: c#

[image]

So i added the `NameValueCollection` to the `Properties.Settings` just by clicking the dropdown and browse for it.
But now when i build the application this property is not added in the .config file for some reason.

Looking into the `Settings.Designer.cs` file, i am guessing this part should be modified too for the type of 'NameValueCollection`:

```
    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public global::System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection strColExcelFamNames {
        get {
            return ((global::System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection)(this["strCol"]));
        }
        set {
            this["strCol"] = value;
        }
    }
```

So my question is, how to proper add the `NameValueCollection` for use in the `Properties.Settings` ?

Comment: There are many things that cant be used in Settings - usually because there is no default way to serialize them to XML.  A Dictionary is one of these and I suspect the same of NameValueCollection because of the similarity

Comment: http://scottdorman.github.io/2008/03/16/namevaluecollection-and-.net-configuration-files/